# Blackberry App: Push with phonegap while app is closed

Tags: cordova, blackberry, push

I general question, (sorry if duplicate, I searched this site for about a day)

I built a blackberry webworks app (for webworks 5+) in phonegap (2.3). App works fine, it registers with the BIS service and I can do a push notification to the app, but only when the app is on screen.

Basically I want to notification to show up similar to android or ios, where it pops up or goes to a message center.

How do I go about this, is it how I handle the app when it's closed, or do I need to setup some type of listener event?

Thanks to any help

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `launchApplicationOnPush()` on the PushService instance.

Check out the [`successCreatePushService` method in the pushCapture sample](https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/blob/master/pushCapture/www/js/common.js#L716) for a working example.